# Solaris cluster - what is running where

Tags: solaris, cluster

how can one tell which resources (FS, process etc....) are part of a specific cluster configuration? IE: after logging in to the global zone, how can I identify the resources that are running under cluster monitoring?

Regards,
Edoardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the iformation with the command: *scrgadm -pvv*

cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
scstat
```

[See the scstat(1m) man page.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19528-01/819-0582/6n30g7ig1/index.html)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.

I'd like to know which processes are spawned within a single resource group or which scripts are called by it. I already uses scstat to figure out the rg-s on the domain, now I need tyo know what these resources actually provide...

TIA

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question - will "ptree" tell you what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

`crlg show -v` and `clrs show -v`

if you are using Sun Cluster 3.2.

`man -s 1CL intro` has a mapping of SC3.1 to 3.2 syntax.